# Imported text data to variable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I have a little problem while creating my UWP program using VB.
I'm downloading text file that has coordinates. And what I would need that every of those is a variable that later I can count.

```
X   Y
231.15  154.65
574.89  123.78
257.15  468.98
487.87  789.97
531.15  124.65
524.89  223.78
657.15  668.98
347.87  389.97
```

I don't have any idea where to start. Any clues?

Comment: Google is a good place to start.  Try "vb.net read text file" (58,000 hits on just this site).  Or gosh, trot over to MSDN; that is where they hide lots of information like this

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where to start since your question seems pretty sparse on details, but if you're considering making all of those variables, consider using a two-dimensional array instead. It'll save you a lot of effort and make your application run faster.